# Switch function in react component not working as logic would suggest

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my react code does not execute as logic would suggest:

I am trying to create a page that resembles an email app.
I have components in React which I import into my message(main) component (e.g. Inbox component, send mail component etc). I have a useState, which is set to 'inbox' as default and a switch statement which checks which value is in the state and returns the component matching that case. I also have a onclick function which changes the state value based on which email tab you want to view (e.g. Inbox or trash etc). When the state changes the component should run the switch statement in my page render and display the correct component in the main component, which is does most of the time.

My problem comes when I keep switching between the tabs which have components it at some point goes to the default of the switch statement which does not make sense because either of the values should have passed.

Please help

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

// Components to be displayed
import Inbox from './Inbox';
import SendMessage from './SendMessage';

// Other components on the page which you can ignore
import Navbar from  '../Layout/Navbar';
import Copyright from '../Layout/Copyright';
import SendMail from './SendMail';

//Material ui for styling
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import ControlPointIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ControlPoint';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const list = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Singing lessons', message: 'We are practicing at 5:00'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Meeting', message: 'Hi Guys, we can meet during lunch at Nandos'},
  {id: 3, title: 'New Product release', message: 'Hi guys, we are encouraging everyone to buy in on the new product'}
]

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex'
  },
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
      zIndex: '0'
    }
  },
  appBar: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    },
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  listItemStyle: {
    marginTop: '50px'
  },
  newMessage: {
    fontSize: '40px',
    backgroundColor: '#64b5f6',
    borderRadius: '50px',
    color: '#fff',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: '50px',
    right: '50px',
    '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: '#1976d2'
    }
  }
}));


// Main component
const Message = (props) => {
  const { window } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = useState(false);
  const [tabTracker, setTabTracker] = useState('Inbox');


  const renderSwitch = (param) => {
    switch(param) {
      case 'Inbox':
        return <Inbox />;
      case 'Send email':
        return <SendMail />;
      case 'Drafts':
        return 'Draft';
      case 'Trash':
        return 'Trash';
      case 'Spam':
        return 'Spam';
      case 'newMessage':
        return <SendMessage />;
      default:
        return 'foo';
    }
  }

  const tabControl = (e) => {
    setTabTracker(e.target.firstChild.data);
    //renderSwitch(tabTracker);
  }

  const newMsg = (e) => {
    setTabTracker(e.target.attributes[5].value);
    //renderSwitch(tabTracker);
  }

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Divider />
      <List className={classes.listItemStyle}>
        {['Inbox', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text} onClick={tabControl}>
            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {['Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text} onClick={tabControl}>
            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );

  const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>
        <Navbar />
      </span>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
          {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
          <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
            <Drawer
              container={container}
              variant="temporary"
              anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
              open={mobileOpen}
              onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
              ModalProps={{
                keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
              }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
          <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
            <Drawer
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
              variant="permanent"
              open
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
        </nav>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            {renderSwitch(tabTracker)}
          <Link href="#">
            <ControlPointIcon value="newMessage" primary="newMessage" className=        {classes.newMessage} onClick={newMsg} />
          </Link>
        </main>
      </div>
      <Copyright />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

// ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
//   /**
//    * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
//    * You won't need it on your project.
//    */
//   window: PropTypes.func,
// };

export default Message;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.target` gives you the element on which click was actually triggered, so when you have multiple elements as children within `ListItem`, its possible that you would have clicked on `ListItemIcon` and hence `e.target` is `listItemIcon` which was not your intention as it will give you an incorrect value for `e.target.firstChild.data`

So you could either use `e.currentTarget` which will give you the element on which the onClick listener is attached or you could simply pass on the information to tabControl by using an inline arrow function

```
const tabControl = (value) => {
    setTabTracker(value);
}

const drawer = (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Divider />
      <List className={classes.listItemStyle}>
        {['Inbox', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text} onClick={() => tabControl(text)}>
            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {['Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text} onClick={() => tabControl(text)}>
            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, thank you so much. I changed e.target to e.currentTarget and it works perfectly